# How to marshall pointer to array in C#

Tags: c#, interop, marshalling, .net

I have c++ method with int** argument which is pointer to int array.

How can I marshall it to C#?

Comment: Not posting this as an answer because I can't confirm it; but try marshalling the parameter as `ref int[]`.

Comment: Tried this. Doesn't work

Comment: @Redwan - what does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @Bond - System.AccessViolationException is thrown

Comment: I would try with ref IntPtr, but not sure.

Comment: Maybe [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3203143/650012) can also be of some help.

Comment: It is not my case. I have pointer to array, which is declared as pointer. Not array itself.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to get inspiration from this method signature:

```
void MyMethod([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst=10)] int[] ar);
```

(The array is 10 in length)

Comment: Don't forget to add the "using System.Runtime.InteropServices;"

Comment: Additionally, you can have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Nah, that won't work. My array doesn't have const size. it varies from call to call. And I can't put nonconstant data in attribute.

Comment: How about something like : void MyMethod([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType=VT_I4)] int[] ar);

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.varenum.aspx for alternatives to the "VT_I4" safe array sub type.